# Traded like 12$ of ethereum for husky at like 6 GWEI how long do those trades usually take?

Tags: transactions, gas, gas-price, gas-limit, gas-estimate

I tried using "UniSwap" but 40$ prices for a 12$ trade seemed ridiculously high so I just went on a random site which allowed me to change "gwei" and I put it to 6 I think, I also heard u lose your "gwei" when u cancel the trade so how long should I expect it to be on average? weeks, months?
edit: ok i dont think its gonna go through like ever still want your opinion tho, and am i losing my gwei when i cancel the trades

Comment: "I just went on a random site which allowed me to change "gwei" what a random site? are you using metamask (u can change the price there), AND you should not connect to a random site it's very risky??. Anyway, you can't cancel a transaction after sending it, you can just replace it with another transaction (same nonce, but could be another trade, transfer or sending 0 ether to yourself) while it still in pending status. You lose your "gwei" only when the transaction is mined which probably will not happen.

Comment: Take care don't send a new Transaction with a new "nonce" because it will be stuck until the first transaction "old nonce" with your 6 gwei is mined (will probably never happen)

Comment: ye i am using metamask it wasnt really a totally random website just the one i found has gwei available to change its zerion  ty tho

Comment: Any updates, How long did your transaction took?